# Creating Group for multiple columns with multiple duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

The below table contains details of members and their policies. We need to form a group of 2 or more members if they have at least one policy in common.

```
Member_ID   Policy
101         X1
103         Y2
104         Z1
101         Y1
102         X1
101         X3
103         Z1
101         X2
102         Y3
105         Y1
```

**Required result:**

```
GROUP   Member_ID   Policy
1       101         X1
1       101         X2
1       101         X3
1       101         Y1
1       102         X1
1       102         Y3
1       105         Y1
2       103         Y2
2       103         Z1
2       104         Z1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a graph-walking algorithm.  This is complicated because you may need to traverse multiple levels.  For instance:

```
101    X1
102    Y1
102    Y2
103    Y2
103    Z1
104    Z1
```

These are all in the same group by 101 and 104 have nothing in common.

Recursive CTEs can handle this.  For this problem, it looks like:

```
with edges as (
      select distinct t.memberid as m1, t2.memberid as m2
      from t join
           t t2
           on t2.policy = t.policy -- and t2.memberid <> t.memberid
     ),
     cte as (
      select m1, m2, convert(varchar(max), concat(',', m1, ',', m2, ',')) as members, 1 as lev
      from edges
      union all
      select cte.m1, e.m2, concat(members, e.m2, ','), lev + 1
      from cte join
           edges e
           on cte.m2 = e.m1
      where members not like concat('%,', e.m2, ',%') 
     )
select m1, dense_rank() over (order by min(m2)) as grouping
from cte
group by m1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c85b4649031e72a8e4e9f0b9ed46924) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Taking a lot time to process in terms of 10k records.

Comment: @Dinesh . . . You can take the `edges` CTE and materialize that as a table, with a primary key on `(m1, m2)`.  That should help a bit with performance.

Comment: Lionff...  Tried with the solution given and materialize edges as table. But the below query runs for *indefinite time for larger table*

`cte as (
      select m1, m2, convert(varchar(max), concat(',', m1, ',', m2, ',')) as members, 1 as lev
      from edges
      union all
      select cte.m1, e.m2, concat(members, e.m2, ','), lev + 1
      from cte join
           edges e
           on cte.m2 = e.m1
      where members not like concat('%,', e.m2, ',%')`