# Recursion for forming groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, recursion

I need to from a group for 2 or more Members, if either of below condition is true;

1) Members having at least one of Policy_1 in common

OR

Members having at least one of Policy_2 in common

2) One member can not be part of two groups

Table we have

[image: Table we have;]

[image: Output Required]

Output Required

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tweak on your earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771198/creating-group-for-multiple-columns-with-multiple-duplicates), changing the definition of `edges`:

```
with edges as (
      select distinct t.memberid as m1, t2.memberid as m2
      from t join
           t t2
           on t2.policy1 = t.policy1 or
              t2.policy2 = t.policy2
     )
```

I would strongly recommend that you save this in a temporary table with a primary key on `(m1, m2)` -- as suggested in a comment on that question.

Comment: Thanks for the help but as already mentioned on the question, need recursion for efficient result.

Comment: @Dinesh . . . The recursion part is the same.  This is the only difference.